# Dataset with the same triples as both row and column headers

Tags: dataset, associations

I have a list of triples and a matrix. I want to use the triples as header for row and column in a dataset so that it looks like this:

[image]

But with the code I have so far it makes the wrong associations:

```
header = IntegerDigits[Range[3], 2, 3];
tbl = {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}};

data = 
  Dataset[AssociationThread[header, tbl]]
    [All, AssociationThread[header, Range[Length[header]]]]
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: From your previous question you should know that you have to use `header = ToString /@ IntegerDigits[Range[3], 2, 3]`

Comment: @eldo, yes, but it will create a string as header obviously. What if I want the header as lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following produces a dataset that ***displays*** like the one you show in your question. It may not have the behavior you want, but since you didn't make it clear what that behavior is, I can't do more.

```
header = IntegerDigits[Range[3], 2, 3];
tbl = {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}};
MapThread[
  Association@*Prepend,
  {MapThread[Rule, {ConstantArray[ToString /@ header, Length @ header], tbl}, 2],
   " " -> # & /@ header}] // Dataset
```

[image: dataset]